# Why do I have to keep adding using directives in child classes that inherit from a parent with them already?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have an abstract class that contains all of my using directives, but I have to keep adding the `using` directives to my child classes?

- Do I put `using` inside or outside of the namespace?
- Is there a way that the child classes can inherit all or some of the `using` directives in the abstract, parent class?

**MyAbstractClass.cs**

```
using System.IO // Do I add it above "namespace" or inside namespace?

namespace MyNamespace
{
    // Do I add "using System.IO" here??
    public abstract class MyAbstractClass
    {   
        protected abstract void DoSomething;
    }
}
```

**A.cs**

```
// using System.IO; // Why do I need to keep adding this?
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class A : MyAbstractClass
    {
       protected void DoSomething()
       {
           // Do something that depends on System.IO
       }
    }
}
```

**B.cs**

```
// using System.IO; // Why do I need to keep adding this?
namespace MyNamespace
{   
   public class B : MyAbstractClass
   {
       protected void DoSomething()
       {
           // Do something that depends on System.IO
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: btw. using "the right" tools, you just type the class and the ide will automatically add the usings for you. So perhaps the solution is not to search for a way to "share" using but to optimize your toolchain.

Comment: I'm new to C#/VS so any tool suggestions are appreciated

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/devecosystem-2020/csharp/ contains a section for IDEs.I'm using Visual Studio Professional + ReSharper. Rider seems to be good too and works on Linux,...